# Undefined type of arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible to make undefined type arrays in C, similarly to Object arrays ? If so, how ? Something like this,

```
undefinedtype ArrayName[200];
```

Comment: @haccks can you help me understand why this works ? what does `typedef name` mean ? I am familiar with only something like `typedef int newintname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. In C, when you create an array, the system allocates memory for your array. It needs to know how much memory to allocate. Objects of different types require different amounts of memory, so if you don't know what kind of objects  will be in your array, you won't know how much memory to allocate.

However, you can make an array of pointers by using void* instead of undefinedtype. Then you can make those pointers point to any kind of object you want later.

Comment: does this work like `typedef ArrayName[200];` like @haccks suggested in the comments ? or is this different ? i can understand that memory needs to allocate memory for the array. I am trying to make a pointers list, rather than an array if that makes sense

Comment: hmm, so any idea what @haccks was trying to say there with his comment ? what does `typedef ArrayName[200]` actually do ?

Comment: @Shiro No ideas. Just string typedef ArrayName[200] gives a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Either use just a vanilla `void *` array, or create a base Object struct of your own to contain metadata and a reference.

Using a `void *` array:

```
void * objArray[200];
int x;
char * s = "hello";
float f;

objArray[0] = &x;
objArray[1] =  s;
objArray[2] = &f;
```

This works, and is easy, but requires great care to avoid getting the actual type of the "objects" mixed up.

Using a wrapper with useful meta-data:

```
// enum to list the types of objects you expect and know how to handle
typedef enum { 
   INT_TYPE, FLOAT_TYPE, MY_TYPE /* etc, etc */ 
} ObjectType;

// structure containing the pointer & associated metadata (e.g. type and size)
typedef struct {
   ObjectType object_type;
   size_t     object_size;
   void *     object_ref;
} Object;

// Array of objects.
Object objArray[200];

// Store an object and some meta-data.    
objArray[0].object_type = INT_TYPE;
objArray[0].object_size = sizeof(int);
objArray[0].object_ref  = malloc(sizeof(int));
((int*)objArray[0].object_ref) = 100;
```

You'll see the latter construct in libraries that deal with JSON, XML, and various other non-native "types" / objects, as well as in the internal implementations of languages with richer type systems.

Answer (score 0):

No, you couldn't make such array. You could declare array with fixed size containing pointers to void. And then dynamically allocate memory for data with needed type.